# Could the quantum wave function collapse under these settings?

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-information, double-slit-experiment, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-eraser

I am wondering if this type of experiment been done.
You observe the phenomenon either by the usual double slit exeprimenet and by delayed choice experiment.
You record the which way path as usual.
You would naturally expect that wave function collapsed because it was recorded.

1.
However, imagine that the recording mechanism was destroyed before anyone looked at the screen.

What would be the result then?

2.
Now imagine that you recorded the which way path as far as you were concerned only to realize that your mechanism wasn't functioning. The fuse was burned and you never paid attention.
What would be the result then?

3.
Now imagine if the instrument got stolen and destroyed, never had a chance to observe the result.  Infromation lost.
What would be result?

4.
But wait,,, by some freak act of nature years later, you came to find out that somehow the instrument was found not by act of looking for it but just by chance and you see the recording.
Then what happens to the wave function?

5.
What if as far as you were concerned you were not recording anything at all.
But someone sneaked in and recorded the which way path.
What would you see who wasn't messing with anything?

6.
What if you send a signal but you don't record the return signal?

I guess my point with all of the above is to prove if JUST SENDING A SIGNAL and not any signal but one that actually interacts that cause a wave function to collapse.
It most likely a misnomer that the recording or the some living person observing it that causes the wave function to localize.

Comment: It has already been answered in this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59974/   and here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646332/

Comment: The first link is all over the map. It uses the word camera.  I use the word signal, a signal that interacts. My questions are clear and specific.

Comment: What causes a wave function to collapse is not ust sending a signal or it being viewed by human directly or via camera in the future. A wave function collapses when it interacts with the external environment that it did not include initially. So a wave function collapses when it entagles with something other than what it describes! Please see the link two.

Comment: I make specific points while both of those posts are in generalities.   I am simply stating that it is sending of a signal, not any signal but a signal that interacts that causes other states to cease but one.   And that it is not the recording or knowing or having access to the information.   The question is, is there a proof that it is not the case  but the recording of the information ( the return signal being recorded) or furthermore one must have access to the information?

Comment: External environment could mean anything.  I say specific things.  That is what signal means.

Comment: That is if a tree falls in the forest it won't make a sound for you if you weren't there not for anyone else that wasn't there, but it will make a sound for all other things in the vicinity. You as an observer or your recorder or your camera or your signal is not needed.  That is my point.

Answer (score 3):

A measurement is simply an interaction between the object being observed and some measuring device. Whether a human looks at it, or the device is subsequently taken to a dump etc etc  is entirely irrelevant.