# Copenhagen interpetation applied to a video recording

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

I always get a little confused when it comes to the Copenhagen interpretation, and especially the fact that (for instance as per this article https://medium.com/science-and-philosophy/the-copenhagen-confusion-611f31cc27e1 ) it is often "wrongly interpreted" as a collapse of wave function upon measurements. Some more old-fashioned styles of this interpretation then related measurement to an entanglement of processes in the brains with reality, etc.

Now, I can understand why this interpretation of the Copenhagen interpretation is not considered "right". But I still get confused when it comes to a simple video recording.

So I have this simple question.

If you record an event, on a VHS tape - for the sake of tangible illustration, VHS works great. For instance, the result of some interaction through particle acceleration, or decay of a particle. You could even record the visualisation of a different visualisation, like of a graph, although this complicates matters a little.

Then, what does the correct "Copenhagen interpretation" say about the state of the VHS tape when it's not been actually observed yet in any way, and if it is the only recording of the event. Does the tape exist in superposition? That seems silly, but at the same time, is it silly?

I'm getting a little frustrated with the tribalism involved in "correct" or "wrong" interpretations of quantum mechanics and would just like to know what they say about the video tape example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will a wave function collapse if the observer was only a camera and the video was watched later in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646332/) In a nutshell: the confusion is between philosophical and physical meaning of *observer*,

Comment: Thanks, I believe it does (I wasn't careless, I looked for the words "copenhagen video recording"). I think I'd still like to know what the 'right Copenhagen theory' says though.