# Observer effect with humans

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

According to the observer effect, physical systems can behave differently when there is an ‘observer’. This has been [demonstrated](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1998/02/980227055013.htm) in cases where the ‘observer’ is a machine.

It seems logical that if machines can effect processes, than human beings can do this too. After all, our bodies work in some ways like a complex machine.

Has it ever been experimentally demonstrated that observation by human beings can effect physical processes?
A way to check this would be: repeat the physical process twice. The first time, a human only observes the result at the end. The second time, he observes what happens throughout the entire process.

Remark
As I said above, it is very clear that the observer effect can happen when the observer is a machine. My question is, whether this can also happen when the observer is a human mind, and whether this has been experimentally verified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will a wave function collapse if the observer was only a camera and the video was watched later in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646332/)

Comment: *Observer* in QM is not necessarily a human being.

Comment: To "observe" just means to interact with, usually for the purpose of measurement. *Any* interaction from anything at all. Nothing about humans, machines, perception, consciousness, or anything like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an observer in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9857/)

Comment: I am going to ask a new question. I see that I can’t un-submit the question for review.

Comment: I don't think it's a well-phrased question, but I do technically disagree that it is the same question as the links provided. The person asking the question wants to know what the difference is between a "machine" performing the experiment and a human. I think from his perspective this "machine" is different than the "camera" described in the linked duplicate question/answer.  And I think the answer to his question is addressing how a camera really is the same as a machine (and therefore the other question provides the answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Has it ever been experimentally demonstrated that observation by human
> beings can effect physical processes?

If the question is just, "is there evidence that humans have observed systems that are changed when they are observed?", the answer is that yes this is the whole point of quantum mechanics.

If your question is that if it is required for a *human mind* to be the thing that is collapsing the quantum state, then this is a less-accepted, less-popular [interpetation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-minds_interpretation).  I believe most physicists would insist that there is nothing special about the mind and that a simple detector can create this effect of collapsing a state.

If you want an experiment that tries to look at the difference between when you make a measurement of something, versus when someone else (human or detector) makes a measurement of something -- this creates a paradox in typical interpretations of quantum mechanics. The paradox is known as the [Wigner's friend problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend).

I suggest reading more about the Wigner's friend problem if you want to try to understand some of the pecularities of what happens when you think seriously about wavefunction collapse in qantum mecahnics.

Comment: As I made clear in my question, quantum systems can be influenced by machines which are not a humans mind. My question is: is it also possible that a quantum systems to be influenced by the human mind?

Comment: "As I made clear in my question" -- apparently not. Your question has -4 votes at the moment, so I think you should be more open to the idea that you are the one that isn't being clear with what you want to understand. 
Additionally, I think that I have addressed what you have asked. Perhaps you should read my answer more carefully?

Comment: I have read through your answer. If I understand it correctly, you distinguish four cases about what my question may be. However, I think that my question does not fall in any of those four categories.

Comment: Your first paragraph is not exactly what I am interested in; I know that humans have observed 2-slit experiments which were also observed by a machine. However, the machine was the thing that influenced the experiment and not the human begin.

Comment: The second paragraph seems to be about the question whether the observer effect is possible without a human mind. In think that this is possible, because it had been experimentally demonstrated. However, this is not my question.

Comment: The third paragraph seems to be about experiments with multiple observers. I am interested in experiments with only 1 observer, which is a human being

Comment: The fourth paragraph is about wavefunctions; so the theory behind quantum mechanics. My question is more like a yes/no question, and is about whether some experiment has been succesfully carried out.

Comment: Please let me know if I have misunderstood something

Comment: "The second paragraph seems to be about the question whether the observer effect is possible without a human mind. In think that this is possible, because it had been experimentally demonstrated. However, this is not my question. " A theory in which collapse ONLY happens due to the mind is currently supported by all experiements. It's not a popular view, but it is consistent. I think if you disagree with this, you should try to study the Wigner's friend problem to understand why this interpetation is viable.

Comment: You are forgetting that someone needs to check the results of what the machine observes, that ITSELF is an observation performed by a human mind. Performing an experiment with just machines will always involve human minds collapsing the state unless the results of the experiment is never actually observed by any human (defeating the point of the experiment). Therefore the experiment you are asking about is impossible. This is why you need multiple observers to evaluate and understand what you are asking. (which is what wigner's friend is about)

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand what the problem is with my question. I will ask a new question instead

Answer (score -1):

Observation affects measurements in quantum systems. Humans (and other similar life forms) behave classically. So, there can not be an experiment conducted, in which observations affect measurement...

Comment: What do you mean by ‘humans behave classically’? Humans consist of small particles which obey quantum mechanical laws

Comment: Yes , but the scales a human can observe are scales in which nature behaves classically. On the contrary, a detector can have resolution small enough to observe properties of small particles that behave quantum mechanically, such as the electron. Human eye can not observe a single electron

Comment: There are also macroscopic quantum effects. But anyway, it seems then that the answer to my question is ‘no’.